# Does the Aitareya Brahmana ask sudras to serve the other three castes?

Tags: rig-veda, caste-system, shudra, aitareya-brahmana

I'm sorry, I don't know the exact verse however I'm attaching a verse from (Aitareya Brahmana of the Rigveda, Published 1922, The Panini Office, Allahabad)
[image: verse]

Comment: It is better to use text format instead of images of text. If possible kindly type it. It becomes easier to search and is also convenient for people using [screen readers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader).

Answer (score 1):

The idea that Sudras should serve the three higher varnas is there in the Gita also.

> Agriculture, cattle-rearing and trade form the duty of the Vaisya
> springing from his own nature, while the natural duty of a Sudra
> consists in subordinate service under others.

**Gita 18.44**

Why is Gita saying this? First get rid of the idea that this verse is talking of caste as practiced by Hindus today. This is talking of varna which is linked to Guna and Karma. What the Gita is saying is that a person whose mind is dominated by Tamasa Guna should serve others whose minds have a larger influence of Sattva Guna. This would gradually help broaden the mind of a person with Tamasa Guna by seeing the conduct of the person being served and help in his spiritual advance. This is an example of Karma Yoga.

> In times of yore a twofold spiritual path was taught by me. O sinless
> one - that of knowledge for Samkhyas (who are pure contemplatives), and
> that of action for Yogis (who combine detached work with devotion).

**Gita 3.3**

The problem with the quote in the Brahmana is the claim that drinking water or food from a person with Tamasa Guna would cause children to have minds dominated by Tamasa Guna and they should be beaten etc. When reading these type of statements in Hindu scripture, one has to remember the rules of exegesis given in our scriptures and by the greats.

Bhishma said in Mahabharata:

> Even the words heard from an ignorant person, if in themselves they be
> fraught with sense, come to be regarded as pious and wise. In days of
> old, Usanas said unto the Daityas this truth, which should remove all
> doubts, that **scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand the
> test of reason**.

**Mahabharata Shanti Parva Section CXLII**

Acharya Shankara, for example, in his Gita Bhasya 18.66 says:

> The appeal to the infallibility of the Vedic injunction is
> misconceived. The infallibility in question refers only to the unseen
> forces or apurva, and is admissible only in regards to matters not
> confined to the sphere of direct perceptions, etc ... **Even a hundred
> statements of sruti to the effect that fire is cold and non-luminous
> won't prove valid. If it does make such a statement, its import will
> have to be interpreted differently. Otherwise, validity won't attach
> to it.** Nothing in conflict with the means of valid cognition or with
> its own statements may be imputed to sruti.

**REF: Srimad Bhagavad Gita Bhasya of Sri Sankaracarya translation by Dr. A. G. Krishna Warrier, p. 629.**

Yoga Vasistha II.18 says:

> yuktiyuktamupādeyaṃ vacanaṃ bālakādapi | anyattṛṇamiva tyājyamapyuktaṃ
> padmajanmanā || 3 ||
> The remark of a child is to be accepted, if it is in accordance with reason; but the remark of even Brahma Himself, the creator of the world is to be rejected like a
> piece of straw if it does not accord with reason.

**REF: Vasistha's Yoga translated by Swami Venkatesananda, p 35.**

Sri Vachaspati Mishra, another Advaita Vedanta philosopher, says,

> Na hy āgamāḥ sahasram api ghaṭam paṭayitum īṣate (Bhāmatī,
> Introduction) A thousand scriptures cannot make a jar into a cloth.

**Bhamati by Vachaspati Mishra**

The quote from the Aiterya Brahmana is undoubtedly repulsive to the modern mind. However, Hindus are not supposed to read their scripture in a fundamentalist manner. Any thing in scripture that is repulsive should be rejected since that repulsive part is not scripture. Hindus are only to seek the truth and not mindlessly support scripture where it is obviously wrong. This is not just my opinion but given in scripture itself. Even the Vedas can be questioned. So the offensive part of Aiterya Brahman should be robustly rejected.

Comment: Beautiful answer sir !

Comment: *"So the offensive part of Aiterya Brahman should be robustly rejected."* - Offensive **to who ?** There are verses in scriptures that say criminals should be punished severely. As a criminal, I find it offensive, so I robustly reject it. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: One knows when one's argument is self serving,

Comment: Questioner is looking for explanation to particular context from Aitareya Brahmana. Though this answer explains the relevant information from other texts yet the essential part (Explanation for Aitareya Brahmana quote) is missing.

Comment: @Pandya Sir what else can we say? Are we justifying the cruelty ?

Comment: @ram Stop justifying every verse!We aren't blaming "Bramhins". Even if we do, people like you will justify all evils committed in name of Religion. How can you justify this verse?  Swami Vivekananda wrote in a letter “It cannot also be doubted that sometimes the Shudras used to be oppressed more than the helots among the Spartans and the negroes among the Americans! As for myself, I have no partiality for any party in this caste question. Have you read Vidura Niti? Knowing how painful to oneself one must not do it to others. If you were born as a Sudra/Dalit would you support this cruelty?

Comment: @ram Where is that love, that weeping heart at the sorrow of others?  Dry pedantry of the Pundit  and the feeling of only oneself getting to salvation hurry-scurry! But is that going to be possible? Was it ever likely or will it ever be so? Can anything be attained with any shred of "I" left anyhow? Please keep hand on your heart and ask yourself. Ofcourse you have narrowed your heart!

Comment: @ram He who injures living creatures, injures Him; for Hari is all beings. Keshava is most pleased with him who does good to others, who never utters abuse, untruth, who never covets another’s wife or another’s wealth and who bears ill-will towards none; who neither beats nor slays any animate or inanimate thing; who is always desirous of the welfare of all creatures, in whose pure heart no pleasure is derived from the imperfections of love and hatred.(Vishnu Purana 3.8.9-12)

Comment: @ram Men are seen to own men as slaves, and by beating, by binding, and by otherwise subjecting them to restraints, cause them to labour day and night. These people are not ignorant of pain that results from beating and fastening in chains. In every creature that is endued with the five senses live all the deities. There are men that live by trafficking in living creatures!(MB Santi CCLXII )
One should never do that to another which one regards as injurious to one's own self. This in brief is the rule of Righteousness.(MB Anu Section CXIII)

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru - you keep on harping that Sudras are ill-treated. Do you know that Brahmanas are NOT allowed to earn money by going for a job ? Do you know they are NOT allowed to drink alcohol, or eat meat (except in sacrifices) ? They can only BEG for money. How demeaning is that ? Where is that love, that weeping heart at the sorrow of brahmins ? Please keep hand on your heart and ask yourself. Of course you have narrowed your heart!  If you were born as a Brahmin would you support this cruelty?

Comment: @ram I am born in a Bramhana family only but I don't justify crimes committed by my ancestors like you. I know all this Kindly read all verses that I gave. No one is saying Sudras serving masters is Unjust. No need to beg for Bramhanas in Grihastya state because Kings give everything easily to Bramhanas. Protest is about beating a Sudra servant and protest is against saying a Sudra can never earn money and protest is against asking Sudra to massage feet of Bramhana like a Menial. Mahabharata Vishnu Purana condemn such cruelty. Vaishnava Acharyas also denounce such practices unlike Smartas

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru - who said *YOUR* ancestors committed crimes ? Who said 'MY* ancestors committed crimes ? Do you have any proof that Sudras were ill-treatd that what is commonly repeated by politicians to get votes ? Do you have a guilty complex just because everyone is accusing your ancestors of mistreating them ? Which king gives brahmins money ? If a student can be beaten to improve him (spare the rod, spoil the child), why can't a servant be beaten to improve him ? Would you rather prefer if the servant became worse due to lack of discipline ?

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru - Do managers not punish employees who perform poorly in annual reviews ? Isn't that corporate slavery, even in modern 2020 ? You are lodging a complaint that Sudras should not massage brahmana's feet. Did you lodge the same protest when Brahmanas are supposed to BEG for money ? There are no kings to donate to brahmins today. Every varna has a role to play. There is no hatred between varnas. Some varnas have extreme rules to follow, so they get corresponding respect. Other varnas have no rules to follow, so they get corresponding respect.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru - Doesn't a 12th man tie a batsman's shoes in cricket? Doesn't a ball boy in tennis carry dirty wet towel used by a player ? Why should the substitute or ball boy touch the feet or handle someone's sweat ? THIS IS MODERN SLAVERY !!!

Comment: @ram Dear Sir please listen to me! I am not a Anti-Hindu! If you are there on Quora, Please read my answers on Caste system and destroying My Enemies : https://www.quora.com/profile/%C5%9Ar%C4%ABvatsa/answers/Indian-Caste-System
I personally love Bhagavadgita,Bhagavatam and Upanishads. But I am very very much depressed when I see these kind of verses. I feel Ethics taught in Puranas Epics and Upanishads are superior to Smritis
Could you really help me because you (after seeing my answers) understood that I am a sincere seeker desperate to understand Hinduism??

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru - I totally understand you feelings. We are on the same side of Sanatana Dharma. What I want you to understand is called 'nuance'. Is varna-ashrama dharma wrong ? No. Should Shudras serve Brahmanas ? Yes. Should that cause pain to Shudras ? No. Are Shudras denied Moksha ? No. Are Brahmanas superior to Shudras ? Yes. Can Brahmanas ill-treat Shudras because of this superiority ? No. Are Shudras denied Vedas ? Yes. Are Brahmanas denied office work/earning money ? Yes. Should that cause pain to Brahmanas ? No. Each varna should follow ITS OWN rules.